# How to set Firebase Hosting Headers based on a specific target?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Using Firebase Hosting, I am able to set headers using the `firebase.json` file.

Is there a possibility to set headers based on the Firebase `project`/`target` used?

E.g., having the following targets:

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "myproject",
    "staging": "myproject-staging"
  },
  "targets": {
    "myproject": {
      "hosting": {
        "site": [
          "the-site"
        ]
      }
    },
    "myproject-staging": {
      "hosting": {
        "site": [
          "the-site"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I set *some* headers configured in `firebase.json` depending on the target?

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "target": "site",
    "public": "...",
    "rewrites": [
      ...
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "X-Content-Type-Options",
            "value": "nosniff"
          },
          {
            "key": "My-Custom-Header",   <---- This should only be applied if the target is staging (or it's value should be different for the default target)
            "value": "DENY"
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So when I do

- `firebase deploy --project default` I want `My-Custom-Header` to have the value `ALLOW`
- `firebase deploy --project staging` I want `My-Custom-Header` to have the value `DENY`.

Comment: Maybe adding a predeploy script in package.json which edits firebase.json depending on which command you ran would work...

Comment: Yeah thanks, this would be a technical possibility but feels hacky and unstable. Therefore I'd prefer if there's another option to directly configure it as it's possible with the different projects/targets.

Comment: years later, I would be interested in this too